# How to Tests for a specific module under a project in Jenkins through maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2, jenkins, continuous-integration

I use Jenkins to build my  project which has multiple modules. This project has a root pom.xml which build all the modules under that project. I specify this pom.xml as the root POM.

Now I want to run tests as a **"post-build step"**. But, I don't want to run all the tests under all modules. I want to run tests only under a specific module.

I tried using the shell command to change the directory to the module for which tests has to be run and then trigger maven. I also tried using the -f switch to specify the pom.xml for that particular module. Both of these steps are not working.

Please help me guys in resolving this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just run from the root path:

```
mvn -pl :submodule test
```

protip: `mvn --help`

Comment: I found that -f and -pl behaved the same.

Comment: You need a : infront of the artifactId, for example: mvn -pl :artifactId test